# SQL Queries in Biq Query with Average

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery, datatable, average

I am trying to answer two questions:

- a) How do I convert a data field from string to integer and find the average of the data field?
- b) How do I obtain to find the average based on unique values?

I have the data table in the following way:

| Product | Trouble |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

I want to write a SQL query that extracts information in the following way:

[image: Outcome]

I want to achieve the following outcome:

- a) Count the unique trouble and product id in table
  i.e. The combination of Product id: 1 and Trouble id:1 total count should be shown in a different column in the outcome data table.
- b) Display the averages on turnover days on business days(BUSINESS_DUR) and calendar days (CALENDAR_DUR), based on the combination of unique combinations mentioned in question 1.

I have attached my query for everyone's review:

```
    SELECT PRODUCT_VAL, TROUBLE, 
     AVG(CAST(BUSINESS_DUR AS INT64)), 
     AVG(CAST(CALENDAR_DUR AS INT64)) 
    FROM  CUSTOMER ASSURANCE TABLE
    GROUP BY PRODUCT_VAL, TROUBLE
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help!!

Comment: Replace your images with formatted tables to get a better response.

Comment: Thank you so Isolated and Jaytiger for your assistance in editing my question!